# I made a (very simple) programming language in Lua, but I can only execute one command

Tags: lua

Hello people of stackoverflow, I've made a (very) simple programming language, it kind of looks like minecraft commands. Here is the code

```
function wait(cmdSleepGetNum)-- you can name this function
--what ever you want, it doesnt matter
  local start = os.time()
  repeat until os.time() > start + cmdSleepGetNum
end



local input = io.read()



if input == "/help" then
print"you'll find it out"

else if input == "/say" then
print"what do you want to say?"
local cmdSay = io.read()
print(cmdSay)

else if input == "/stop" then
os.exit()

else if input == "/sleep" then
print"how long?"
local cmdSleepGetNum = io.read()
wait(cmdSleepGetNum)

else if input == "/rand" then
local randNum = math.random()
print(randNum)
end
end
end
end
end
```

Now I know what you are thinking "what is the problem here?" the problem is that I can only execute one command and after that command is finished by the Lua interpreter, I cannot execute any other commands.

for example:

/rand
0.84018771715471 (the /rand command is executed and prints out a random number)
/rand
stdin:1: unexpected symbol near '/' (this happens when i try to execute another command)

Comment: Wrap your program in `while true do ... end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you replace `else if` with `elseif`, you won't need so many `end`'s,
2. You can get rid of `if`'s altogether, is you use a table,
3. As @Egor Skriptunoff said, you need to create a main loop to run many commands,
4. I suggest that you add an optional argument to `/sleep` and `/say`.

```lua
local function wait (cmdSleepGetNum) -- you can name this function
-- whatever you want, it doesn't matter.
  local start = os.time ()
  repeat until os.time () > start + cmdSleepGetNum
end

local commands = {
    help = function ()
        print "you'll find it out"
    end,
    say = function (arg)
        if arg == '' then
            print 'what do you want to say?'
            arg = io.read ()
        end
        print (arg)
    end,
    stop = function ()
        os.exit ()
    end,
    sleep = function (arg)
        if arg == '' then
            print 'how long?'
            arg = tonumber (io.read ())
        end
        wait (tonumber (arg))
    end,
    rand = function ()      
        local randNum = math.random ()
        print (randNum)
    end,
    [false] = function ()   -- fallback.
        print 'Unknown command'
    end
}

-- Main loop:
while true do
    io.write '> '
    local key, _, arg = io.read ():match '^%s*/(%S+)(%s*(.*))$' -- you can type /sleep 1, etc. in one line.
    local command = key and key ~= '' and commands [key] or commands [false]
    command (arg)
end
```